# how to configure IIS for mvc4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc4 applications. I am trying to run an asp.net application in mvc4. I configured by right clicking on the project and setting the URL to local host under the web tag.

While running the application I found below error:

"Unable to launch IIS Express webserver, port 80 is in use"

I am also running SQL server on my computer possibly its using the port 80. 
I tried to change the port number  but it does not work. 
I am using the administrator account.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to determine who is using port 80.

I like using [ActivePorts](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Protocol-Analyzers-Sniffers/Active-Ports.shtml) for this.

Comment: $10 says its IIS.  Usually you use use IIS Express on a different port.

Comment: do IIS, IIS express web server and visual studio server use the same (reserved-80) port or any random ports?

Comment: from few tutorials i found that, MVC application on IIS server shows only the name of server and name of the project(applicaiton) like http://localhost/MvcDemo. whereas the visual studio server shows any random port like http://localhost:32286. so when i configure and run the mvc application using  local host IIS server then i get the error "Unable to launch IIS Express webserver, port 80 is in use". when i use the application on visual studio serverthen it does not show any problem.